# How to revoke all authorizations (to private data) given to Xiaomi in MIUI?

Tags: security, privacy, xiaomi, miui, authorization

On Xiaomi Mi Note 10 there are three prompts asking for authorizations:

- When opening Bereinigung (the stock cleaning app; I tried using that because I still [can't delete caches with Xiaomi Mi Note 10](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/249620/cant-clean-app-caches-on-xiaomi-mi-note-10))
- Two prompts when installing any new app (I think it used to be two)

I accidentally pressed confirm to the prompt when opening Bereinigung (shown in the left/first screenshot) and I think I accidentally pressed confirm to one of two prompts after installing an app (now it only shows one prompt when installing an app shown in the right/second screenshot).

The text says something like (it's in German in the screenshot):

> In order to use the basic features of this service, you must agree that Xiaomi will collect, process and use your personal data

and

> Grant authorization
> Virus scan is provided by Xiaomi. To be able to use this feature normally, you must allow Xiaomi to collect, process, and use your personal information (including the data related to your usage of this feature which will be used for content recommendation) in accordance with the Privacy Policy

I didn't actually meant to press confirm but the button appeared where I meant to press another button just before the prompt showed up. And I don't even want to use these features either.

**I'd like to revoke these authorizations, how can I do so?**

[image: Xiaomi cleansing - authorization prompt]
[image: Xiaomi app install virus scan - authorization prompt]

I checked "Authorization & Revocation" in the settings, but there

- it does not display the Bereinigung app or general app install related authorizations but just a few apps that I haven't disabled so far: "Updater", "Updater for System-Apps" and "Security"
- authorizations can't be revoked for the few remaining app: when pressing revoke it just loads "Revoking authorization" and then displays "Could not revoke authorization"; and for the apps that this worked it required retrying it many times.